# Salesforce DocuSign API Sync Issue

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

New to the forum :) - first post. I am trying to set up DocuSign in Salesforce for a client and keep running into an issue when trying to create an envelope template. Some context: my client has a DocuSign Business account (not Gen/ Negotiate), I have added the documents, and can add non-merge fields fine. The only issue is when I try to *place* the merge field, not create it, I receive an error:
Save Error: Some fields might be out of sync. Unable to connect to the service. Failed to connect to the salesforce service.

So far I have tried: adding IP addresses to Salesforce, removed MFA authentication for API, I have tried clearing cache and cookies, in different browsers, and in incognito mode - no success. I think I just have missed a step in set up? OR is this just not a feature of the client's current account and they need to enable the "Gen" feature to use merge fields?

Appreciate the help - I am also new to Salesforce administration and coding - so I am learning as I go and bear with me if I am not picking up all the "lingo" up front.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the legacy DocuSign for Salesforce package if you're not using Gen/Negotiate, so there are typically a couple of issues that could cause the error that you're seeing. The first is a caching issue, so you could try in an incognito browser or by clearing cache and cookies for the browser.

The other issue could be that the connection between DocuSign and Salesforce was broken and needs to be connected again. If that's the case, you could follow the steps in [this article](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Update-Salesforce-Credentials-in-DocuSign). If you're still running into problems, I'd advise to reach out to the DocuSign support team so that they can take a look with you (https://support.docusign.com/).